# Why does Keychain ask for the login password twice to show a password?

Tags: password, keychain, authentication

Whenever I want to view a password in my Keychain, it asks me the login keychain password twice:

1. First like this:

[image]

2. Then like this:

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding why. I am running macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score -1):

The first message is your keychain asking to access the data in google drive itself. That data im referring to is your google drive password and other info. The second message is asking you to allow your google drive protected key to decrypt its data to reveal your stored google drive password. Essentially the first one is asking you if its okay to unlock google drive itself, and the second is for your mac to unlock and decrypt google drives protected key in the keychain. They are two different unlockables.